# Get an object inside the ngOnInit

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I get an object that is inside the ngOnInit function and take it out of the class within the same component? I explain: I am using the Angular Material table and replace the static data with the ones I receive from firebase.

```js
    ngOnInit() {
      this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(products => {
      this.products = products;})
    }

    const products = []

    const ELEMENT_DATA: Element[] = products;
```

Link to the project can be found [here](https://stackblitz.com/angular/beggoegpvmk?file=app%2Ftable-filtering-example.html).

[image: Second Screenshot]

Comment: You mean use it  like `this.products` outside the `ngOnInit`?

Comment: why on earth would you want/need to do that? What's wrong with using the `products` in your component?

Comment: `replace the static data with the ones I receive from firebase.` Do you mean to ask how do you populate the const array with the data you have received from your API?

Comment: At the time of doing this: `const products = [ this.products ]`, I get this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'products' of undefined`

Comment: Don't make it constant if you plan to change it. use `let products = ['some', 'initial', 'values']` and then reassign after your api call. `service.getProducts().subscribe(newProducts => this.products = newProducts)`

Answer (score 1):

Just don't use a const. this.products is going to be usable everywhere in your component.

```
products = [];

ngOnInit() {
  this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(products => {
    this.products = products;
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to do that at all. Just use `products` as the data source:

```
dataSource;

ngOnInit() {
 this.productService.getProducts()
   .subscribe(products => this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(products))
}
```